# User clicks on a link with a hash value to visit the page what happens if Javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get this functionality going but am a bit uncertain and don't know how to approach it. I have a master page with a div called "masterDiv". 'masterDiv' makes a load() call and loads content of an external html page called "details.html" from it content div. This is how I am doing it:

```
  $('#masterDiv').load('details.html #content');
```

content loads up as expected and the url address pops in as "http://www.xyz.com#details"

This is all good and working, but then I thought of those users who may not have JavaScript endabled. I figure I would just direct those users to 'details.html' page directly instead of having the "Master Page" load the content from "details.html" page. So now here is the issue, lets say if I send a user this link:

```
    http://wwww.xyz.com#details
```

And if that user's browser doesn't have Javascript enabled then obviously JQuery cannot be invoked and therefore load() call will not be made and so on. how can I direct the user to  "details.html" page directly, please?

Any insight would be wonderful

Thank you.

Comment: Nothing you've posted suggests JavaScript is required. You shouldn't be using JavaScript at all to build the core functionality of your website, it's a terribly bad practice for exactly the reason you're running into. You can't use JavaScript to solve the issue of disabled JavaScript.

Comment: @meagar : You can enhance the functionnality when js is enabled though. His question makes it look like he's trying to load a page asynchronously. Perhaps that's what his goal is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link probably looks like this :

```
<a id="myLink" href="#details">Link that the user clicks</a>
```

When the user clicks the link, jQuery load is called. Is that correct?

If so, you could instead have your link like this :

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://wwww.xyz.com/details.html">Link that the user clicks</a>
```

That way, when the page loads, the link will work for everyone (even those with javascript disabled). Then, when the page first loads :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myLink').attr('href', '#details');
});
```

will set the link to the way it was before. That way, only users with Javascript enabled will use the load version. The other ones will simply be redirected to details.html

If there is something I haven't understood correctly in the question let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I direct the user to "details.html" page directly, please?

By making the link's href attribute "details.html". The way every link works by default.

```
<a href="details.html">Details</a>
```

Every link on your site should be built this way. That is how the Internet is designed to work, and how it works best. You should only add functionality with JavaScript if you actually *need* to, you shouldn't be depending on it for something as fundamental as linking between pages.

Comment: Further to this, if you want to add fancier navigation with JS you can, but you should leave the standard href attributes in place as a default just as meagar said.